# Properties of (Af)(x, y)= (x+iy)f(x,y) on compact domain

Tags: operator-theory, banach-spaces

Consider in $L^2(Q)$, where $Q=[0,1]\times[0,1],$ the linear operator:
$$(Af)(x, y)= (x+iy)f(x,y)$$
 1. Show that A is bounded
 2. Calculate $||A||$
 3. Calculate $A^\dagger$

---

I'm unsure about my solution I would very much appreciate if someone could check it and give me some suggestions.

1. $$||A||=||x^2f(x,y) +iy^2f(x,y)|| \le (x^2+y^2)||f|| < \infty$$
   Since $f \in L^2(Q)$, $||f||$ is limited in Q and Q is compact (we can be sure given Weierstrass that $x^2+y^2$ won't diverge).
2. $$||A||=\sup_{||f||=1}||f(x,y)(x^2 +iy^2)||=1$$
3. $$A^\dagger=(x-iy)f(x,y)$$

Comment: Be careful about what means the norms:
$$\|A\| = \sup_{f\in L^2(Q)}\frac{\|Af\|_{L^2(Q)}}{\|f\|_{L^2(Q)}}$$.
Since $|x|,|y|\leq1$, we have
$$\|Af\|_{L^2(Q)}=\left(\int_Q|(x+iy)f(x,y)|^2dxdy\right)^{1/2}\leq \sqrt{2}\|f\|_{L^2(Q)}$$
and , we deduce
$$\|A\|\leq\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: @VeridianDynamics you are right! But I don't undertand why you elevated the integral at 2 power

Comment: @VeridianDynamics is it somwthing like the gauss integral?

Comment: sorry, I mistype the $1/2$, but I edited it

Comment: @VeridianDynamics so also in point 1. I should correct the inequality by writing: $\frac{||x^2+y^2||||f||}{||f||}$ and having so point 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1 and 2, 
\begin{align}
\|Af\|_2^2=\int_0^1\int_0^1 (x^2+y^2)|f(x,y)|^2\,dx\,dy
\leq2\int_0^1\int_0^1 |f(x,y)|^2\,dx\,dy=2\|f\|^2.
\end{align}
So $A$ is bounded and $\|A\|\leq\sqrt2$. Now, for any $n$,  let $f=1_{E}$, where $E$ is the rectangle $[1-1/n,1]\times [1-1/n,1]$. Then 
\begin{align}
\|Af\|_2^2&=\int_0^1\int_0^1 (x^2+y^2)|f(x,y)|^2\,dx\,dy\\ \ \\
&\geq\left((1-\frac1n)^2+(1-\frac1n)^2\right)
\,\|f\|^2.
\end{align}
So, for any $n$, $$\|A\|\geq\sqrt2\,(1-1/n).$$ It follows that $\|A\|=\sqrt2$.

For the adjoint, you have
\begin{align}
\langle A^*f,g\rangle
&=\langle f,Ag\rangle
=\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(x,y)\,\overline{(x+iy)g(x,y)}\,dx\,dy\\ \ \\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^1 (x-iy)\,f(x,y)\,\overline{g(x,y)}\,dx\,dy\\ \ \\
\end{align}
As $g$ is arbitrary, it follows that $(A^*f)(x,y)=(x-iy)f(x,y)$.